# Скачивание с https через wget

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Хочу скачать файл таким образом:

```
wget https://grafanarel.s3.amazonaws.com/builds/grafana-4.1.2-1486989747.linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
--2017-02-20 16:38:54--  https://grafanarel.s3.amazonaws.com/builds/grafana-4.1.2-1486989747.linux-x64.tar.gz
Распознаётся grafanarel.s3.amazonaws.com (grafanarel.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.64.192
Подключение к grafanarel.s3.amazonaws.com (grafanarel.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.64.192|:443... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа... 200 OK
Длина: 45024995 (43M) [application/x-tar]
grafana-4.1.2-1486989747.linux-x64.tar.gz: Отказано в доступе

Невозможно записать в «grafana-4.1.2-1486989747.linux-x64.tar.gz» (Выполнено).
```

На сайте указан `SHA` ключ такого вида: `e2de61dde3286f586d27c670eb50a5fddf6b6926`. Куда мне его нужно ввести для успешного скачивания ?

Comment: ...и вообще лучше `lftp` использовать -- куда больше возможностей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никуда никакие ключи писать не надо. Архив по ссылке доступен анонимно и ответ  200 OK это подтверждает.

У пользователя, от имени которого вы вызываете wget не прав на создание файла в директории, откуда вы вызываете команду. Поэтому скачивание успешно начинается, а результат писать некуда.

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте права доступа в текущем каталоге, проверьте права на файл `grafana-4.1.2-1486989747.linux-x64.tar.gz`, если он существует

```
ls -ld . grafana-4.1.2-1486989747.linux-x64.tar.gz
```

2. Перейдите в свой домашний каталог и там скачайте файл

```
cd
```